# Remove last 3 characters of string or number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove last 3 zeroes here: `1437203995000`

How do I do this in JavaScript? I'm generating the numbers from new `date()` function.

Answer (score 202):

Here is an approach using `str.slice(0, -n)`.
Where **n** is the number of characters you want to truncate.

```js
var str = 1437203995000;
str = str.toString();
console.log("Original data: ",str);
str = str.slice(0, -3);
str = parseInt(str);
console.log("After truncate: ",str);
```

Answer (score 69):

**Remove last 3 characters of a string**

```
var str = '1437203995000';
str = str.substring(0, str.length-3);
// '1437203995'
```

**Remove last 3 digits of a number**

```
var a = 1437203995000;
a = (a-(a%1000))/1000;
// a = 1437203995
```

Comment: That's a nice method! Here's a function for general use: `function removeDigits(x, n){ return (x-(x%Math.pow(10, n)))/Math.pow(10, n) }`, in which `x` is the number you'd like to remove digits from, and `n` the number of digits you'd like to remove.

Comment: Brilliant suggestion indeed, @Oscar!

Comment: Is the method for removing 3 last digits of a number more efficient than using toString() and then substring?

Answer (score 6):

you just need to divide the Date Time stamp by 1000 like:

```
var a = 1437203995000;
a = (a)/1000;
```

Comment: question was from both string or number,. This answer just helps with number but what about string???

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 1437203995123;
var b = (a / 1000) | 0; // 1437203995

// Note: Operator | ( Bitwise Or ) with ZERO converts value to integer 
// by discarding any value after decimal point 
// 0.9 | 0  ==> 0
// 0.1 | 0  ==> 0
// "string" | 0 ==> 0
```