# How to remove the last few characters of an ISO date with JavaScript in jmeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I wanted to create a dynamic date variable in JMeter. Following responses in  [Jmeter - get current date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043029/jmeter-get-current-date-and-time)
I found that the following works:

`${__javaScript(new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()+6)).toISOString())}`

It sets a value of this variable 6 months in the future. Perfect.

The problem is that the formatting I need this date to be is:
`2024-03-21T10:10:10`

But the above line results in:
`2024-03-21T20:54:55.386Z`

I need to get rid of the last few characters but I'm not sure how to handle that on one line.

Using substring or slice would be ideal but it doesn't work. The result is blank. I'm guessing that I'm using a wrong syntax. Thinking I can't use substring on a date, I tried to wrap it into a `new String` but that doesn't fix it either.

For example,

`${__javaScript(new String(new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()+6)).toISOString()).substring(0,18))}`

What am I doing wrong here?

*As a side note in case if anyone wants to suggest timeShift JMeter function, I can't upgrade my JMeter version just yet because of other reasons so I need to use what works in version 2.13.
I'm hoping that there's a way to accomplish this by other means, for example with JavaScript.*

---

UPDATE:
Here is what I've finally figured out.

The following worked like a charm:

`${__javaScript( new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()+6)).toISOString().split('.')[0])}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove last 3 characters of string or number in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489413/remove-last-3-characters-of-string-or-number-in-javascript) Adapt to the number of characters you need to remove.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No. That does not help me or answer this question. I need to put it all on one line like in the code snippet I listed. All my attempts using slice or substring haven't worked yet.

Comment: It most assuredly answers the question posed in the title, "How to remove the last few characters of an ISO date with JavaScript?" `new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -5)` produces a string exactly in the format you said you wanted. Whether it works in JMeter is something you'll need to work out for yourself.

Comment: If you change that to `-5` instead of `-3` (as I said, you need to adapt the answer to the number of characters you need to remove), The code between the parentheses of `__javaScript(...)` returns the value you want. So would changing `.slice(0, -5)` to `.substring(0,19)` if somehow JMeter runs a version of JavaScript that doesn't support slice with negative indexes on `slice`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, it could be a jmeter-specific problem. Thankfully, I found a way to make it work with split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `split` and `join`:

```js
var date = new Date()
var dateString = date.toISOString()
var shortDate = dateString.split('.')[0]

console.log(shortDate) // 2023-09-21T22:29:56
```

Comment: Split worked. I was able to put it all on one line too like this ${__javaScript( new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()+6)).toISOString().split('.')[0])}. So I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Good to hear. I usually use it with input date fields as well, but the split on the 'T' to get the last part without hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about jmeter, but will this work?

```
${__javaScript(new Date(Date.now() + 182 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString().substring(0, 18))}
```

Comment: you cannot do arithmetic with dates

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev `Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds. You can do arithmetic with numbers.

Comment: @jabaa nope, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time + timezone changes

Comment: @jabaa adding like 5 minutes within a day is probably ok, but adding months, years is no-no due various time shifts

Comment: @jabaa I'm not about using Date objects, i'm about dates as dates. Actually you can do arithmetics with Dates: Date.now() === new Date - 0

Comment: I'd use regular expression for that.

new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 6)).toISOString().replace(/\.\d{1,}Z$/, '');

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev You wrote: _"you cannot do arithmetic with dates"_, but you can and it makes sense. `new Date(Date.now() + 182 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` is the current date + 182 days.

Comment: @jabaa nope, not always, if you encounter Daylight_saving_time you fail. I've seen such cases. Date math is no-no. Use setMonth(), setHour() and so on. JS knows better how to do date additions

Comment: @jabaa you can have days with 23 or 25 hours

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev There is a difference between "you can't do arithmetic with dates" and "you shouldn't do arithmetic with dates".

Comment: @jabaa ok, you can do, but the logic is wrong

Comment: @jabaa do arithmetic with timestamps and get calls twice a year from customers with DST, no problem

Comment: @devnull69 I wish it worked but it doesn't.

Comment: Check the latest edit ... I missed a closing `)`

Comment: @devnull69 Unfotrunately not. Perhaps jmeter doesn't like substring. But split worked for me so problem solved. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
const date = new Date();
const isoDate = date.toISOString();
const dateOnly = isoDate.substring(0, 10);

console.log(dateOnly); // e.g., Outputs: 2023-09-21
```